# Configuring Unicorn & Sidekiq correctly on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, unicorn, sidekiq

I was getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac` errors so I followed this [guide about deploying Unicorn to Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) and it seems to have fixed it. However under [caveats](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn#caveats) it shows how to configure `Resque` for such a setup - would I have to do something similar with `Sidekiq`?

Sample code from Heroku:

```
before_fork do |server, worker|

  ...

  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis.quit
    Rails.logger.info('Disconnected from Redis')
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  ...

  # If you are using Redis but not Resque, change this
  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = ENV['REDIS_URI']
    Rails.logger.info('Connected to Redis')
  end
end
```

This is what I currently have set up:

config/unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes 2
timeout 30
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end  

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 1 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { :size => 6 }
end
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e production -c 4
```

Answer (score 17):

As of version 2.9.0 of sidekiq, no configuration is necessary in unicorn/passenger `after_fork`.

Here are the [release notes for version 2.9.0](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md#290) with the issue mentioned.

Here's the [resolved issue](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/794) that addresses forked connections.

Finally, here's a [comment from the maintainer](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/120#issuecomment-17149729) confirming that configuration in `after_fork` is no longer required.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I have and it works:

config/unicorn.rb

```
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 5)
timeout 15
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { size: 1, namespace: 'sidekiq' }
  end
end
```

config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
ENV["REDIS_URL"] ||= "redis://localhost:6379"

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: ENV["REDIS_URL"], namespace: 'sidekiq' }
end

unless Rails.env.production?
  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV["REDIS_URL"], namespace: 'sidekiq'  }
  end
end
```

Note: I use `thin` on development and `unicorn` on heroku.

Comment: This works for me.  I use unicorn for both development and production so I don't need a sidekiq.rb initializer, but the unicorn initializer is pretty much exactly the same as mine.

Comment: I see you've configured a namespace for the Sidekiq client. Does that mean you've configured one for the Sidekiq server elsewhere?

Comment: @steven_noble yes.  you can see it under `Sidekiq.configure_server` block.